# Service Fabric Stateful Service Remoting V2

Tags: azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateful

I have a Stateful Service called by a Stateless service, in .Net Standard Asp.net Core 2.0 running on Visual Studio 15.4.
I can't make the Service Remoting V2 work.

The old code in the Stateful service that worked for V1 is **not valid** anymore

```
  protected override IEnumerable<ServiceReplicaListener> CreateServiceReplicaListeners()
    {
        return new List<ServiceReplicaListener>()
            {
                new ServiceReplicaListener((context) =>this.CreateServiceRemotingListener(context))
            };
```

I tried to follow this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-communication-remoting#how-to-use-remoting-v2-stack) but the example is for the **stateless** one.

I tried to change the code in this without success.

```
protected override IEnumerable<ServiceReplicaListener> CreateServiceReplicaListeners()
    {
        return new List<ServiceReplicaListener>()
            {
                new ServiceReplicaListener((c) =>new FabricTransportServiceRemotingListener(c, this))
            };
    }
```

Also there are no instructions on how or where to use this code in the tutorial

```
var proxyFactory = new ServiceProxyFactory((c) =>
   {
       return new FabricTransportServiceRemotingClientFactory();
   });
```

I'm stuck, could someone show me how to make it work?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your stateful service, in method `CreateServiceReplicaListeners`, use this code:

```
protected override IEnumerable<ServiceReplicaListener> CreateServiceReplicaListeners()
{
    return this.CreateServiceRemotingReplicaListeners();
}
```

And in the file that defines your remoting service **interface**, add this:

`[assembly: FabricTransportServiceRemotingProvider(RemotingListener = RemotingListener.V2Listener, RemotingClient = RemotingClient.V2Client)]`

(for example, just below the `using` namespaces list.)

Add the endpoint:
`<Endpoint Name="ServiceEndpointV2" />`

And rebuild the client.

Comment: could you give some details on how to call this once setup? As in the client side.

Comment: Create a ServiceProxy using the service url, and partition key (if stateful) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-communication-remoting#call-remote-service-methods

Comment: I've done this and it still doesn't work. This answer just repeats what's in the tutorial mentioned above on learn.microsoft.com

Comment: Important point is that "[assembly: FabricTransportServiceRemotingProvider(RemotingListener = RemotingListener.V2Listener, RemotingClient = RemotingClient.V2Client)]" should also be added to the client assembly, not only service.

Comment: I ended up having to do   return Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Remoting.Runtime.ServiceRemotingExtensions.CreateServiceRemotingReplicaListeners(this); and inheriting from IService