# Lost CreateServiceRemotingListener when upgrading to version 3 of of service fabric

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I've upgraded my service fabric app to version 3, CreateServiceInstanceListeners method looks like this:

```
    protected override IEnumerable<ServiceInstanceListener> CreateServiceInstanceListeners()
    {
        return new[] { new ServiceReplicaListener(context => this.CreateServiceRemotingListener(context)) };
    }
```

Unfortunately CreateServiceRemotingListener method is no longer available. (I still have a using declared: "using Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Remoting.Runtime;")

Does anyone know how I update my code for the new SF version?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using

```
return this.CreateServiceRemotingReplicaListeners();
```

and

```
return this.CreateServiceRemotingInstanceListeners();
```

Seems to have fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected override IEnumerable<ServiceReplicaListener> CreateServiceReplicaListeners()
{
    return this.CreateServiceRemotingReplicaListeners();
}
```

from https://stackoverflow.com/a/46753002/2021224